# OneSignal provisionator tool doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, onesignal

every time i try to save i get following message: "Your production certificate was rejected by Apple. It may be expired, revoked, or invalid."
I also tried to upload the .p12 file to firebase messaging and there it worked right away! So it seems as if there is something wrong with OneSignal.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: I actually managed to do it one year ago and now when I tried to renew the certificate it just won't work.

Comment: exactly same problem

Comment: Yes there is a problem on onesignal like nearly a day, still the problem persists

Comment: same problem here!

Comment: anyone managed to do it yet?

Answer (score 2):

They just answer me this:

> Hello We have fixed an issue causing iOS certificates not uploading. 
>   Everything should be working correctly now with our Provisionator Tool
>   and Dashboard Uploader. Please try again and sorry for the
>   inconvenience. Thanks

and now its working normally :D